# pict2e doesn't draw filled circles at specified point

Tags: diagrams, picture-mode

When compiling the pict2e code below I don't get the expected output of a red circle with a "white hole" (doughnut shaped figure). Instead it places one of the circles slightly off the specified center point.

```
\begin{picture}(80,80)
  {\color{xred}\put(40,40){\circle*{80}}}
  {\color{white}\put(40,40){\circle*{40}}}
  \put(40,40){\circle{80}}
  \put(40,40){\circle{40}}
\end{picture}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Can anyone explain this seemingly strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, not just fragments.

The colour specials interfere with picture commands attempts to ignore white space, it is safer to put them *in* the `\put`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pict2e,color}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(80,80)
  \put(40,40){{\color{red}\circle*{80}}}
  \put(40,40){{\color{white}\circle*{40}}}
  \put(40,40){\circle{80}}
  \put(40,40){\circle{40}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have spurious spaces in fact of the first `{...}` Use:

```
\begin{picture}(80,80)
  {\color{red}\put(40,40){\circle*{80}}}%
  {\color{white}\put(40,40){\circle*{40}}}%
  \put(40,40){\circle{80}}
  \put(40,40){\circle{40}}
\end{picture}
```